# Is it possible to use regex in type checking with typescript?

Tags: typescript

Can TypeScript be used to validate the value passed into a function using a regular expression?

For instance, assume that an object is passed to a function as follows:

```
call({
 '/url/to/path': {},
 '/baz/bar/foo': {},
})
```

The object contains URLs as keys and their corresponding values are irrelevant. The goal is to throw an error if the URL is not valid, using a regular expression check.

Is it feasible to perform this type of validation in TypeScript?

Comment: Well, you can create a validate() function. Although I'm not sure if that's what you want since JavaScript can achieve the same. TypeScript's TypeChecking does "type" checking... not "value" checking. If you really want to, you could create a custom class with validation in the constructor.

Comment: Those aren't URLs.

Comment: @jonsud define "valid", it depends on regex

Comment: I don't think is matters because this is an example. the string should be validated against the regex in the type checking. so there I ask if it's possible?

Answer (score -1):

It's

```
function call(O: Record<string, any>) {
  Object.keys(O).forEach(key => {
    if (!key.match(/^\w+$/)) throw new Error(`Expected ${key} to match regex`)
  })
}
```

and it has nothing to do with type checking, that's value checking

Comment: OP is clearly asking for type checking, but they need to add more details for a clear answer to be given.